# How to open a file in another app via an Intent using an URI?

Tags: android, file, kotlin, filesystems, document

In my app, I have several file `Uri` (NOT `URI`) store. These are of the form:

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/427
```

My intention is, once I click a button, open one of these Uri in a file reader (may it be MS Word, Excel, PDF Reader... depending on the extension and device).

I am currently trying this snippet:

```
                val file = File(Uri.parse(uri).path!!)
                val myMime: MimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
                val newIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

                val mimeType: String = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(file.extension).toString()
                newIntent.setDataAndType(
                    FileProvider.getUriForFile(applicationContext, "${applicationContext.packageName}.provider", file), mimeType)
                newIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                newIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                try {
                    startActivity(newIntent)
                } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                }
```

But every time I try to open it, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /document/427
```

Could you please tell me what am I missing? No answers I've found here targeted my problem. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @CommonsWare help, I managed to avoid an Exception, my code now looks like this:

```
val newIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
newIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
newIntent.data = Uri.parse(uri)
newIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
newIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
try {
    startActivity(newIntent)
} catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

I'm getting the Uri from here:

```
val fileResultLauncher =      registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    viewModel.uploadFile(result, false)
            }

fileFab.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.type = "application/*"
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
    fileResultLauncher.launch(intent)
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting a `NoActivityFoundException`

Comment: Try to open and read the uri yourself before you try to let another app do it. I bet your app is not allowed to open it already. Use getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri) and then read from the stream.

Comment: It's a uri to a document (docx, xlsx, pdf...) file. I can't really not use another app for opening it.

Comment: ???? What you say does not make sense at all. You are asking to use another app: `How to open a file in another app via an Intent using an URI?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of:

```kotlin
val file = File(Uri.parse(uri).path!!)
```

...and replace your `setDataAndType()` call with:

```kotlin
newIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(uri), mimeType)
```

Comment: But how about ```val mimeType: String = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(file.extension).toString()``` if I have no File?

Comment: @xvlaze: You could just use `setData()` (or supply the `Uri` in the `Intent` constructor). The document provider for that `content` `Uri` will report to Android what its MIME type is. You do not have to provide the MIME type yourself.

Comment: Tried ```setData()`` and saw some improvement. Thanks in advance! Now I'm getting: ```SecurityException: UID 10262 does not have permission to content://(...) you could obtain access with OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs```. so I changed my Intent type to Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT) but now I get a file picker instead of an "Open With..." disambiguation dialog.

Comment: @xvlaze: If you are trying to persist `Uri` values, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and `takePersistableUriPermission()` is your only option for long-term access to the content. If you are merely trying to pass a `Uri` between activities, either get rid of the activities (and go with multiple fragments or composables) or pass the `Uri` between the activities using `setData()` and `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`. See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html) for more.

Comment: Thank you! Read your article and really liked your blog! I've updated my question with my latest advancements.

Comment: @xvlaze: Sorry, my reference to `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` referred to where you are getting the `Uri` values *from*. You would still use `ACTION_VIEW` to open an app to view the content identified by the `Uri`.

Comment: Updated my question with more info, but still getting ActivityNotfoundException.

Comment: @xvlaze: You could use `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`. Note that some specialized Android environments (Android TV, Wear OS, etc.) will not have support for `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. FWIW, [this sample Kotlin project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/vFINAL/ContentEditor) demonstrates the use of `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument`.

Comment: You mean on my `fileResultLauncher` or surrounding my `newIntent`? Thanks again for your dedication and patience, really helps!

Comment: @xvlaze: I mean instead of `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()`. I do not know where you are getting `ActivityNotFoundException`, so I am assuming it is in that `ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()` request.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'm getting the exception at the `newIntent` part, where I already got the `Uri` from the server.

Comment: @xvlaze: There is not necessarily an app that can view every possible MIME type. However, I would remove `newIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)` and see if that helps.

Comment: Absolutely saved me! THANK YOU SO MUCH! Btw, I'm going to take a look at your book, seems really useful!